# Reset password from windows client

Tags: windows, active-directory, login, samba4

I use Univention operation system (which was built on Debian) and I want on the windows sign in side that when the user click to Reset password then come up a window and load a page where they can request a new password.
I saw this in my school but I don't know how did they. It's neccesary because if all computer connected to AD and there is no wifi then it can be fixed via sign in "Reset password" side in sign in.
So how can I do that in windows sign in side will show the **Reset Password** text or **Forgotten Password** text and when users click to this text then show up a page?

Here is the Univention page if someone don't know (this using samba 4.6): https://www.univention.com/

I hope someone use Univention and I didn't write my question and explanation in chinese language. :D

Answer (score 1):

I am working for Univention, the manufacturer of UCS, which you mentioned, and yes, there are some ways to reset the password:

- [Password change by user via Univention Management Console](http://docs.software-univention.de/manual-4.2.html#user-management:Password_changes_by_users_via_UMC) - in case the the login is still possible, a user can change the password by its own.
- [Password management via Self Service app](http://docs.software-univention.de/manual-4.2.html#user-management:password-changes-by-users:self-service) - users can change their password or reset their lost password.
- [Delegation of the privilege to reset user passwords](http://docs.software-univention.de/manual-4.2.html#domain-ldap:Delegation_of_the_privilege_to_reset_user_passwords) - if you want to setup a group to reset passwords of other users i.e. Teachers can reset students accounts.

The documentation is available in english, german and french but not in chinese - sorry for that :)

You could also take a look our [Help – Forum](https://help.univention.com/) if you have a very specific question.